How to convert public EC key to PGP public key
I have a public EC key which I want to convert to PGP public key using Golang. I found resources to convert RSA key to a pgp key but is it even possible to convert an EC key to PGP public key.
My use case is the EC key is used to sign RPM, and the public converted PGP key will be used by yum/dnf for gpg check
I tried opnpgp library but it is deprecated currently.

Have you looked into the RFC that defines the OpenPGP ECC key file format? https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6637.html
